# Android Tablet IP Webcam App no accessible after few seconds

Tags: tablet

i have an android Tablet (Telekom Puls) with Android 5.0.1 on it. Installed the "IP Webcam" App. When i want to access the Webservice of this App from another Computer in LAN, i get "connection refused" in the Browser.

When i turn off/on the WLAN from the tablet, a few seconds the access from another computer works and i can open the web service. But after few seconds its "refused" again.This happens every time i toggle the WLAN.

I´m New to android, is there any security option, which blocks external access in android OS? I don´t have installed any other firewall or antivirus software.

would be great if some can give me a hint!

thanks and best regards,

dave